# Не устанавливается Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

При установке Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express Edition вылетают следующие ошибки, приведенные на скринах. Никакой конкретной информации в интернете нет.. Строчки лога установщика, когда прекращается загрузка:

(04) 2022-02-22 09:16:02 SetupActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Process finished with exitcode: -2147024893
(04) 2022-02-22 09:16:02 SetupActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Log directory does not exist: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220222_084502'

[image: ошибка базового установщика]

[image: ошибка при установке пакета express core]

Comment: деинсталлировать пробовали?

Comment: Запускаете установку от администратора? Также попробуйте поставить на другой диск, если он есть в системе.

Comment: @Konst да, подчищал все хвосты, службы и тп. Переустанавливал несколько раз - никаких изменений.

Comment: @alexsteeel да, от администратора. Пробовал устанавливать на различные диски, итог одинаковый.

Comment: на какую операционку пытаетесь установить?

Comment: @Konst Win10 Home

Comment: посмотрите тут советы: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/170b5c06-ea19-4a47-9417-0c2cc2dd01e3/cprogram-filesmicrosoft-sql-server140setup-bootstraplog20180907132343-does-not-exist?forum=sqlexpress